# Android Spinner showing transparent screen with distortion of data,but items are selectable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

I have a spinner and i have an arraylist  having the names of the states which I am setting to the spinner using array adapter.I think there is some issue with  the layout of the dropdown_item of the spinner and it is taking the style of the app. Since i have used material style in my project, the same style is getting applied here.

The items are visible the items are selectable also, but the dropdown list is not being displayed properly

Can anybody please help me out.
[image: Something like this]

This is how im setting my arraylist to the spinners.

```
    mArrayAdapter_userType = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RegistrationActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_text, aArrayList_userType);
    mArrayAdapter_userType.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinner_userType.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter_userType);
```

Comment: where am i going wrong? should i  create a new style from the dropdown item.

Comment: you can use custom adapter and change the text color of textview

Comment: You can try creating a custom view and use it as  a dropdownViewResource instead of android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,  additinally from what I'm seeing the simple_spinner_dropdown_item layout is using a CheckedTextView to show data, maybe that is what is mucking up everything

Comment: @Cruces i did not create a seperate CheckedTextView thats the default, when i choose simple_spinner_dropdown_item layout.

Comment: yes that's what I said, that's the default, maybe that's whats causing the problem, you could try creating a customized view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this dependencies in `build.gradle` file

```
 compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
```

In Xml write this code.

```
 <com.rey.material.widget.Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_label"
                    style="@style/LightSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minWidth="128dp"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    app:spn_label="Spinner with arrow" />
```

In Java class write this code.

```
 Spinner spn_label = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_label);
 String[] items = new String[20];
   for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          items[i] = "Item " + String.valueOf(i + 1);
       }
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row_span, items);
 spn_label.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Create **row_span.xml** in your `layout` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.rey.material.widget.TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/row_spn_tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textDirection="locale"
    style="@style/LightSpinner"/>
```

When you run the below output is generated.

[image]

for more detail visit this : https://github.com/rey5137/material

### Without using Any Library :

Write this in your xml

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Create Array data in your resources file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
        <item>Jupiter</item>
        <item>Saturn</item>
        <item>Uranus</item>
        <item>Neptune</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And use this in Java

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: your solution is perfect but, i do not want to use another dependency for a widget. Can u tell u how to find the solution without using the library