# Change appearance of the spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I want to change the appearance of spinner to something like this - 
[image]

Currently, it looks like this -

[image]

What changes do I need to make?

Here's my xml code -

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/country_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview5"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    android:prompt="@string/choose_your_country"
    />
```

In main activity -

```
final ArrayList<Country> countries = addAllCountries();
    countrySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.country_spinner);
    CountrySpinnerAdapter adapter = new CountrySpinnerAdapter(MainActivity.this, countries);
    countrySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependencies in `build.gradle` file

```
compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
```

In `Xml` write this code.

```
 <com.rey.material.widget.Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_label"
                    style="@style/LightSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minWidth="128dp"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    app:spn_label="Spinner with arrow" />
```

In Java class write this code.

```
Spinner spn_label = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_label);
 String[] items = new String[20];
   for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          items[i] = "Item " + String.valueOf(i + 1);
       }
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row_span, items);
 spn_label.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Create **row_span.xml** in your layout folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.rey.material.widget.TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/row_spn_tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textDirection="locale"
    style="@style/LightSpinner"/>
```

**Output :**

[image]

For more detail visit my this answer : [Android Spinner showing transparent screen with distortion of data,but items are selectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608108/android-spinner-showing-transparent-screen-with-distortion-of-data-but-items-are/37608428#37608428)

and for github library visit this : https://github.com/rey5137/material#donation